# How can a user other than superuser access admin site with coloumns of databse populated?

Tags: python, django

I am actually trying to make the ADMIN page in django a page where users will enter and see some columns in the database(SQL in my case).Since,its a very small site with <10 usersMy goal is to:make the users other than super user to enter and view all the entries made by other users (columns of different parameters), but cannot edit any of the fields if he is not the owner.My databse fields are:
Product_name,
Imported_from,
owner_name.

**Models.py**

```
            Product_name = models.CharField(max_length =75, choices=HARDWARE_CHOICES)
            Imported_from = models.CharField(max_length =75,choices=IMPORTED_CHOICES)
            owner_name = models.EmailField(blank =False,null=False,max_length =75)
```

**Admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite
from Inv_Site.models import list_inventory
class DataAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): #Writing Admin Class to make changes in the ADMIN page
    search_fields = ('Product_name','owner_name','Imported_from',)
    list_display = ('Product_name','Imported_from','owner_name')

    def get_form(self, request,obj=None,**kwargs): #Writing function to getform 
           if request.user.is_authenticated():
                 if not request.user.is_superuser:
                      owner_name    =list_inventory._meta.get_field('owner_name')
                      if not request.user.email == owner_name:
                          readonly_fields =     ('Product_name','Imported_from',,'owner_name','Borrower_name',)
       return super(DataAdmin, self).get_form(request,obj,**kwargs)

admin.site.register(list_inventory,DataAdmin)
```

**Error**
I am getting an error:'NoneType' object is not callable
        Request Method:     GET
        Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/Inv_Site/list_inventory/2/
        Django Version:     1.7.5
        Exception Type:     TypeError
        Exception Value:
        'NoneType' object is not callable
        Exception Location:     C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py in changeform_view, line 1419
        Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
        Python Version:     2.7.9
        Python Path:
        ['C:\Python27\Scripts\mysite',
         'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlutils-1.7.1-py2.7.egg',
         'C:\Windows\system32\python27.zip',
         'C:\Python27\DLLs',
         'C:\Python27\lib',
         'C:\Python27\lib\plat-win',
         'C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk',
         'C:\Python27',
         'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages']
        Server time:    Wed, 1 Jul 2015 16:16:52 +0530

Comment: which line is `line 1419`? it seems that there you try to call something that evaluates to `None`.

Comment: Please fix your indentation. It's very hard to work out what is going on in that method.

Comment: Indentation Fixed..Please help me!!